# Can Asynch WebService Callback mechanism work for Java and .NET clients?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, architecture, apache-axis

I have doubts about Async WebService (Java) that supports the Callback mechanism.

I read a few links, and this appears promising:
http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html#Async

Will both Java and .NET clients be able to make use of WebService Callback mechanism?

How does a Callback Handler "really" gets called back.

How does the Service know the location (or address) of the Client... ?  I guess there is some ws-addressing magic involved.. but its that isn't ws-addressing Java specification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WS-addressing has a set of implementation independent parameters. You can use WS-addressing/ async web services with  .NET, Java EE and other languages/platforms. Read more on http://www.w3.org/Submission/ws-addressing